# Update in time in MySQL is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert date time on the MySQL DB. I have kept the field as VARCHAR(9182)

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$timestamp =  date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time());    

$utimeprocess = "UPDATE tabelconf 
                    SET time_of_pstart = '".mysql_escape_string($timestamp)."' 
                  WHERE UniqueID = '".mysql_escape_string($dbUniqueID)."'";

$result = mysql_query($utimeprocess);
```

return of $result is 1

Comment: Sorry, am I missing where it fails?  Is the value of TIME_OF_PSTART not expected?

Comment: it is not showing any errors also.....trying to figure out that

Answer (score 2):

This means it succeeded.  From the [documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For other type of SQL statements,
>   INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success
>   or FALSE on error.

Answer (score 0):

And if you

```
"Select time_of_pstart from tabelconf WHERE UniqueID = ".mysql_escape_string($dbUniqueID) "'";
```

Does it return what you expect? An update will succeed if runs, not only if it updates.